# Would question about cabins in the woods be a good fit?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wanted to ask a question about how to efficiently deal with flies in the cabin in the woods that has outdoor "hole" toilet.

Would Outdoors be a good fit for such a question?

Comment: In my opinion yes, absolutely. Cabin in the woods and issues related to it are well within the scope. Too short to be answer - hence the comment.

Comment: A cabin in the woods with an outdoor hole toilet is absolutely on topic!